# Audio won't play on instantiated object in Unity

Tags: audio, unity-game-engine

I have a Canvas prefab called gameOverScreen which has an audio clip attached to it. It is cloned whenever the following function is called.

```
public static void GameOver()
{
    GameObject gameOverScreen = Instantiate(Resources.Load("gameOverScreen")) as GameObject;
    gameOverScreen.audio.Play();

}
```

The problem is the audio doesn't play. I worked around it by using audio.PlayOneShot() in another function, but is there some reason why it doesn't work in this case?

Comment: When you use audio.PlayOneShot(), how are you referring to the audio clip?

Comment: @Agumander audio.PlayOneShot(Resources.Load("Sounds/Death") as AudioClip);

Comment: It looks like when a prefab is loaded, resources used by the prefab might not be automatically loaded. If this is true, then that should extend to graphics used by the prefab. Is this consistent with what you are observing?

Comment: @Agumander the gui items loaded just fine. Only the audio was problematic and I have no idea why. In the function, everything executes correctly,  except the audio won't play.

Comment: Are the GUI items in the resources folder?

Comment: @Agumander no,  the gui items are children of the canvas prefab

Comment: But do they have any dependencies on separate graphic assets in the resource folder? Like a texture file for the button?

Comment: No... Could that be the problem? It's something easily tested after all..

Comment: How is your sound stored on your prefab ? Through public audioclip, or a resource load call?

Comment: @MXD The canvas has an AudioSource component. I just drag the audio clip file from Assets to that component.

Comment: @geft when playing an audio you also need an audio listener that it's usually attached to the camera so if your camera it's not near to the object you won't be able to hear the audio. Could this be your problem?

Answer (score 0):

In c# you can use this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class SoundController : MonoBehaviour {
    public AudioClip clip;  

    void Start () {
        AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(clip, Vector3.zero, 1.0f);      
    }
}
```

and in Javascript you can use this:

```
var myClip : AudioClip;
function Start () {
 AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(myClip, transform.position);
}
```

But if you want play sound in instantiate:

```
#pragma strict
var prefabBullet : Transform;
var forwardForce = 1000;
var myClip : AudioClip;
function Update()
{
if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire2"))
{
var instanceBullet = Instantiate (prefabBullet, transform.position, 
Quaternion.identity);
instanceBullet.GetComponent.<Rigidbody>().AddForce(transform.forward * 
forwardForce);
AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(myClip, transform.position);
}
}
```